# Is it possible to filter Slicer with selection on table

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix table

Country     | User  | Number of Purchase

Country 1     User1   2

Country 2     User2   5

Country 3     User3   6

Country 4     User4   8

Country 5     User5   6

I have a slicer:
Purchase ID
Purchase1

Purchase2

Purchase3

Purchase4

And at the bottom i have detaled table with purchase:
Purchase1 Utem1

Purchase1 Utem2

Purchase2 Utem1

The thing is that I want to click on number of purchase on 2 for example

Than slicer Purchase ID should be filtered on this selection (All purchases for Country 1     User1

After that I want to use slicer to see selection in detailed table for Purchase 1 or another